# How can I ensure that a JDBC batch insert is done atomically?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, hikaricp

I have the following (pseudoish)code to insert ~5000 rows into a SQL Server table.  I'm using Hikari (`ds`, below, is my HikariDataSource).

```
try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
          "insert into Dog (name, age, breed) values (?, ?, ?)");) {
        
        
        for (Dog d : dogs) {
            statement.setString(1, d.getName());
            statement.setInt(2, d.getAge());
            statement.setString(3, d.getBreed());
            statement.addBatch();
         }
        
         statement.executeBatch();
} 
// catch exceptions, etc.
```

This is working fine (in that the inserts work as expected), but if someone queries the table in the middle of the batch insert (which takes a few seconds), they can get an incomplete set of rows.  I want them to either get nothing (assuming the table is empty to start), or every row I insert.

I assume I need to do something special to lock the table or otherwise perform all of the inserts as a single transaction (I assumed that that's what the batch insert *was* but I was wrong).

How can I do this?

Comment: SQL Server can easily handle inserting 1,000's (even millions) of rows quicky and in one go. In fact 5,000 individual `INSERT` statements would be significantly slower than a single one for 5,000 rows. If you can pass a table type parameter/variable, then you could `INSERT` that whole lot in one go, not have people get impartial results, and it would be faster.

Comment: @Larnu Hmmm - 1) what do you mean by "pass a table type parameter/variable"?  and 2) I'm doing a batch insert where I insert everything "at once" (or so I thought) - am I not "inserting the whole lot in one go" by doing the batch insert?

Comment: Basically what it sounds like. It is a parameter that is a table type. And no, a batch with 5,000 `INSERT` statements won't insert all those rows simultaneously; SQL runs each statement in the batch one after the other, and so each statement in the batch will be run sequentially.

Comment: Each individual insert is autocommited unless you wrap the entire batch in a transaction. A transaction is needed to guarantee all-or-none.

Comment: @DanGuzman Is this as simple as adding `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` before iterating over the Dogs, and adding `connection.commit()` after `statement.executeBatch()`?

Comment: Yes.  Here's the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-transactions?view=sql-server-ver15  using a transaction will also make the batch much faster, as SQL Server won't need to flush the transaction log after each insert.

Comment: @Larnu I understand now that I am still processing the inserts serially, despite the batch insert.  But sorry, maybe I'm being dense but I still have no idea what you mean by "passing a table type parameter".  1) what is a "table type"?  2) pass it where?  to my insert statement?

Comment: See [Using table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15). This [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15#passing-a-table-valued-parameter-as-a-sqlserverdatatable-object) seems quite relevant.

Comment: You would also need `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, otherwise you may get partial results while committing

Comment: @Charlieface - I don't understand.  I thought by definition, performing the insert as a transaction guarantees that if it executes, it executes atomically - i.e. no opportunity for a partial insert.  Is that not the case?  Can you give an example of something could happen without SERIALIZEABLE isolation that could not happen with it?

Comment: @DanGuzman auto-commit behaviour of batch execution is driver implementation specific.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I should have said the default SQL Server database engine behavior is autocommit. Drivers or middleware can override this.

Comment: @DanGuzman JDBC drivers are **required** (by the JDBC specification) to default to auto-commit. However, it is driver specific whether the auto-commit boundary is per parameter set, or for the entire batch, so one should always disable auto-commit when using batches to avoid such implementation specific behaviour.

Comment: The default isolation level is `READ COMMITTED` which guarantees you always read committed data, no dirty reads, but doesn't specify *when* the data was committed, so you may miss some rows or read rows twice. See Paul White's excellent series https://sqlperformance.com/2014/07/t-sql-queries/isolation-levels

Answer (score 0):

By default a connection is in auto-commit mode. The transactional behaviour of batch execution in auto-commit mode depends on the JDBC driver implementation. If you want to ensure they are done atomically, you need to disable auto-commit mode and explicitly commit after executing the batch.

```java
try (Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
          "insert into Dog (name, age, breed) values (?, ?, ?)");) {
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        
    for (Dog d : dogs) {
        statement.setString(1, d.getName());
        statement.setInt(2, d.getAge());
        statement.setString(3, d.getBreed());
        statement.addBatch();
    }
    
    statement.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();
}
```